# Index out of bounds, but index is actually within bounds C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chess

My C# (unity) application claims that an index I am trying to access within an array of strings is out of the bounds of the array. It is not. Here is the array:

```
public string[] fen =   
{
    "2q3k1/8/8/5N2/6P1/7K/8/8 w",
    "7k/8/8/4b1n1/8/8/5PPP/5R1K w",
    "r1bqkb1r/pppp1ppp/2n5/4p3/2B1N3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/R1BQK2R b"
```

Here is the code accessing it:

```
  void Update()
{
    if (PuzzleVariables.instance.puzzlePassed)
    {
        if (PuzzleVariables.instance.fen.Length < PuzzleVariables.instance.puzzlenumber + 1)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene("ModuleCompleted");
        }
        else
        {
            PuzzleVariables.instance.puzzlePassed = false;
            FENbuild(PuzzleVariables.instance.fen[PuzzleVariables.instance.puzzlenumber -1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of moving on to the next puzzle, it goes on to the ModulePassed screen.
Whenever I try printing the length of this array, it reads 1. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Evidently it isn't within the bounds of the array.

Comment: I have a feeling it is out of the bounds of the array you are trying to compare it to. It seems like you are trying to access a static instance of  `PuzzleVariables.instance` which may not have `fen` instantiated. Perhaps posting the `PuzzleVariables` class, or whichever class is actually creating the `fen` array would help.

Comment: From the information you provide we know the `string[] fen` has 3 items and the valid indexes are `[0-2]`. We lack information on the value of `PuzzleVariables.instance.puzzlenumber`. Set a breakpoint at the ´Update()´ method and check the values.

Comment: @Cleptus the value of PuzzleVariables.instance.puzzlenumber is 1. I am trying to access the FEN string at index 1.

Comment: `c#` rutime doesn't just invent exceptions ^^

Answer (score 4):

### First

**When the runtime says that you are out of bounds, then you ARE out of bounds.**

There is no point in arguing that you are not out of bounds with the runtime. Empirically, almost everytime people discuss with their compiler, *(ignoring the fact that the compiler is a bad discussion partner because it will not talk back to you but stubbornly repeat his argument over and over, and is not convincable, and immune to threats of all sorts, like throwing pc out of the window and such)*, it turns out: compiler is right, you are wrong. So skip that episode, and search for the mistake you made instead.

### Second

If Puzzlenumber is anything other than 1, 2, or 3, or the Array is shorter than that (non initialized, using wrong array, etc), this will crash. Place a breakpoint on the line where you access your array, and check your variable and also check `PuzzleVariables.instance.fen.Length`. You might have initialized something you dont use.

#### Third

Stacktrace. Check your stacktrace to see if your line crashes, or the crash is WITHIN the method FENbuild. Maybe  your input is working, but causes a crash down there.

### Fourth

Singletons are only used when there is a technical reason for a class to have only one instance, (i.e. resource, printer, etc.).
Is there a reason why you do not work with normal instances? If not, singleton is an Antipattern.

Is say this, because singletons, can have side effects that also make your thing crash. Especially in a multithreaded environment like unity is.

### Fifth

In Unity Inspector a public string[] fen; might be serialized => it can have totally different content assigned in the inspector, be empty etc. Changing the code afterwards doesn't change the already serialized array => The Inspector overrules any later changes in code unless you Reset the component

## In short:

Please post stacktrace and maybe some reproducable code, and never use singletons.

Comment: adding to this: In Unity Inspector a `public string[] fen;` might be **serialized** => it can have totally different content assigned in the inspector, be empty etc. Changing the code afterwards  doesn't change the already serialized array => The Inspector overrules any later changes in code unless you `Reset` the component

Comment: `Especially in a multithreaded environment like unity is` ... Unity itself is somehow the exact opposite ^^ Most of things from the Unity API can only be used on the Unity main thread ... but I agree regarding the Singletons

Comment: @derHugo yeh but it can be multithreaded, so its a multithreaded environment :D, in opposition to, for example, ABAP or PHP, where there is no support for multiple threads

Comment: I know what you meant ;) It isn't Unity but `c#`/`c++` in general .. I'm just quite confident that if OP doesn't even know how to debug an out of bounds issue .. for sure OP shouldn't be dealing with multi threaded code so far ^^ I would rather assume the simplest case: Array is assigned wrong in inspector or overwritten on runtime

Comment: @derHugo i think you're right

Comment: @derHugo that or the .instance property getter returning new objects instead of the singleton (pattern wrong)